# Apache Camel - What is the difference between <camel:bean and <camel:to

Tags: java, apache-camel, esb

I have a route that get data from a MQ and then I have a sequence like below XML:

```
<camel:bean ref="instruction_handler" method="save"/>
<camel:to ref="instruction_handler" />
```

both will execute sequentially, the only difference I can notice is that the first line calls method "save" and the second one calls the method annotated with "@Handler", looks like no other behavior difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `bean` component like a route and you can use it with beanRef. Documentation of the bean component: http://camel.apache.org/bean.html

So `camel:bean` and `camel:to` are both for invoking a bean. In this case in your first call you've specified the method to invoke, but in the second call you haven't specified the name of the method to invoke, so Camel will choose the method using the following rules (in your case the method decorated with `@Handler`): http://camel.apache.org/bean-binding.html#BeanBinding-Choosingthemethodtoinvoke